# How to obtain an xmlBuf for use with xmlBufGetNodeContent/xmlBufNodeDump etc.?

Tags: libxml2

The [description](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlNodeDump) of `xmlNodeDump()` (which takes an `xmlBufferPtr`) states:

> Since this is using xmlBuffer structures it is limited to 2GB and somehow deprecated, use xmlBufNodeDump() instead.

Fair enough, but since `xmlBufNodeDump()` (and e.g. `xmlBufGetNodeContent`) takes an `xmlBufPtr` my question: How to create such an `xmlBuf` buffer?

I can't find anything obvious.

And how to free it?

I mean, for `xmlBuffer` there is e.g. `xmlBufferCreate()`.

Or is one supposed to obtain an `xmlOutputBuffer` via `xmlAllocOutputBuffer()` and use its `xmlOutputBuffer::buffer`  attribute (of type `xmlBuf*`) for `xmlBufNodeDump()`?

Comment: Today, I have faced same question. Very counter-intuitive API :(

Answer (score -3):

For those who need an answer:

```
xmlBufferPtr buffer;
buffer = xmlBufferCreate();

xmlBufPtr buf;
buf = xmlBufFromBuffer(buffer);
```

Comment: Do you also know how to free it? Could you show it in your answer
?

Comment: Which header declares `xmlBufFromBuffer`? I can't find its declaration under `/usr/include` on a Fedora 27 system (where `libxml2-devel-2.9.7-1.fc27.x86_64` is installed). Also, I can't find it in the online documentation.

Comment: Apparently the function is declared in the library's **private** header file "buf.h" (see https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2/blob/master/buf.h). So it is not of any use for users of the library.

I found no other way to create an XmlBufPtr. This is unfortunate as the documentation of xmlNodeDump recommends the usage of xmlBufNodeDump for which one needs an XmlBufPtr.